# Handling Duplicates in Data Warehouse

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, data-quality

I was going through the below link for handling Data Quality issues in a data warehouse.

http://www.kimballgroup.com/2007/10/an-architecture-for-data-quality/

"
Responding to Quality Events
I have already remarked that each quality screen has to decide what happens when an error is thrown. The choices are: 1) halting the process, 2) sending the offending record(s) to a suspense file for later processing, and 3) **merely tagging the data and passing it through to the next step in the pipeline.** The third choice is by far the **best** choice.
"

In some dimensional feeds (like Client list), sometimes we get a same Client twice (the two records having difference in certain attributes).  What is the best solution in this scenario?

1. I don't want to reject both records (as that would mean incomplete client data).
2. The source systems are very slow in fixing the issue, so we get the same issues every day.  That means a manual fix to the problem also is tough as it has to be done every day (we receive the client list everyday).
3. Selecting a single record is not possible as we don't know what the correct value is.
4. Having both the records in our warehouse means our joins are disrupted.  Because of two rows for the same ID, the fact table rows are doubled (in a join).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sending the offending records to a suspend file for later processing, and using a GUI to fix the offending records seems like your best choice.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best solution in this scenario?

There are a lot of permutations and combinations with your scenario. The big questions is *"Are the differing details valid or invalid?* as this will change how you deal with them.

*Valid Data Example:* Record 1 has John Smith living at 12 Main St, Record 2 has John Smith living at 45 Main St. This is valid because John Smith moved address between the first and second record. This is an example of Valid Data. If the data is valid you have options such as create a slowly changing dimension and track the changes (end date old record, start date new record).

*Invalid Data Example:* However if the data is INVALID (eg your system somehow creates duplicate keys incorrectly) then your options are different. I doubt you want to surface this data, as it's currently invalid and, as you pointed out, you don't have a way to identify which duplicate record is "correct". But you don't want your whole load to fail/halt.

In this instance you would usually:

1. Push these duplicate rows to a "Quarantine" area
2. Push an alert to the people who have the power to fix this operationally
3. Optionally select one of the records randomly as the "golden detail" record (so your system will still tally with totals) and mark an attribute on the record saying that it's "Invalid" and under investigation.

The point that Kimball is trying to make is that Option 1 is not desirable because it halts your entire system for errors that will happen, Option 2 isn't ideal because it means your aggregations will appear out of sync with your source systems, so Option 3 is the most desirable as it still leads to a data fix, but doesn't halt the process or the use of the data (but it does alert the users that this data is suspect).